# html 5 canvas custom shapes without css

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible in html5 canvas to create custom shape canvas like circle, star, rounded corners etc. What I'm talking about here is the main canvas itself not the contents. I already searched for answers and results are by using css. By default canvas is rectangle I want to make it custom shape. I hope this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp i dont think html5 supports rounded corners. As for star and other complicated shapes, you can use javascript with html5 canvas to achieve that

Comment: @JapanGuy, not that it's just drawing shape in the stage. Want I want is a custom shape for the main stage.

Comment: @Defyleiti out of curiousity why did you want that? canvas is jut meant to be a frame. If you set it to invisible you can achieve your shape within the drawing itself

Comment: @Dana, I didn't know that's possible. So setting the display of the canvas to none and drawing the shape makes it possible. thanks

Comment: @Defyleiti you can also change the shape of the canvas itself like any other element. But I don't know a way to do this without css. Here is an example where I changed canvas to be a triangle: https://jsfiddle.net/ej2w1cw2/. Have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/) for more examples

Comment: Have you ever seen an image file that is not rectangular ? Why do you want to do this, if it's only to display it, why not with CSS ? What's the problem with a rectangular canvas with transparent borders ?